# Are IP address links valid in posts?

Tags: discussion, link-rot

I added a link in my post to an IP address based link such as `127.0.0.1/my_awesome_image.png`. It appears that an automatic process added a comment on the post asking me to correct the link.

I know how the Internet works and think it is perfectly valid to have IP address based links. Why are you disallowing this?

Answer (score 11):

From comprehensive analysis of all the out-going links on Stack Overflow it was determined that in the vast majority of cases `IP Address` rooted links are either broken from get go, or break in short order.

We would like to correct this issue as early as possible.

Some statistics:

On the 1st of May 2012 there were approximately 3000 posts on Stack Overflow with IP address based links with a `host` matching the following pattern:

```
\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b
```

The vast majority of these links are broken and/or link nowhere.

To correct this issue:

---

- If it is a legitimate link, find the correct host name and link to it. For example use:

`http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:mystuff`

**And not**

`http://209.85.173.132/search?q=cache:mystuff`

---

- If it is a non-legitimate link, wrap it in a code block by wrapping it with <kbd>`</kbd>.

Comment: @waffles - So when you ban IP based links, are users also going to have trouble posting 127.0.0.1?  That appears frequently in genuine posts, but not as part of a link.  Blocking that address in particular seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: @shanethehat nothing is stopping them posting `127.0.0.1` make it a code block, not a hyperlink

Comment: @waffles - does this also extend to comments, and should existing comments be flagged? ie http://stackoverflow.com/a/7589415/665800

Comment: @shanethehat comments are ethereal, once we sort out post link rot we can consider looking at comments, very low pri imho

Comment: @waffles - cool. And finally, lots of the `127.0.0.1` posts also have a `http://localhost` url that's been auto-hyperlinked. Should they receive the same backtick treatment?

Comment: @shanethehat yes they should

Comment: You're spending time solving a problem that affects ~0.0009% of posts?

Comment: What about the cases where the IP-address links are fully intended?  I was just trying to fix up [an old answer about "valid" IP addresses](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7550806/319403).  In that case, the links are not only *fully intended* (as live examples of how numeric addresses get parsed), but **are globally valid URLs**. Or at least would be, if this damned validator didn't stand in the way and keep me from editing the post...