# Link to relevant meta discussion in 'no numeric IPs' error message

Tags: feature-request, policy, link-validator

As per [this change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131639/are-any-ip-address-links-valid-in-posts), numeric links are considered "invalid" and prevent posting with the message:

> Your post contains a link to the invalid host '74.125.224.135'.
>   Please correct it by specifying a non numeric domain or wrapping it in a code block.

This is a somewhat non-standard meaning for "invalid host", and annoys me a bit because something like http://nonexistenthost.example.com/ (an NXDOMAIN), what I'd consider an invalid host, *isn't* prevented when posting.  [I'm not the only one who's ever been surprised by this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134212/your-post-contains-a-link-to-the-invalid-host-192-168-1-1), especially as noted there, this can happen for text that was automatically link-ified, not a link that I actually made.

Maybe the message could be changed to be more meaningful, but I think that the biggest help would simply be to link to the meta page announcing (and defending) the policy.  Apart from giving anyone who's riled a fuller explanation, this would also facilitate continuous feedback.  As it is, meta can be difficult to search for policy announcements if you don't know exactly what you're looking for.  Providing the relevant links makes the information hugely more discoverable.

Answer (score 2):

This is a good suggestion.  Changing the error message to link to [the meta page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131639/160917) would be useful today.  I suggest linking to this one: [Are  IP address links valid in posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131639/160917)

I ran across this error today.  I tried searching on MSO with the text of the error message, but that didn't turn up the canonical MSO post.  I only stumbled across that MSO post through sheer luck.  Many people probably wouldn't even know to come to MSO for this.

I realize that this probably affects only a tiny number of users so probably is extremely low in the prioritization.  But what can I say?  I'm a perfectionist and can't help noticing opportunities for improvement, even if they are extremely minor.