# Links to IPv6 addresses work as expected in answers, but cannot be used in comments

Tags: bug, comments, hyperlinks

Sandbox example: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/328811/192262

I can type http://[::1] in a question or answer, and it'll automatically turn into a link. I can also use markdown to format it as link, if I wish to give it a custom text.

In comments, however, neither works: it's not autodetected, and `[http://[::1]](http://[::1])` also does not turn into a link.

I'm not sure why the markdown/hyperlink parser handles the two cases differently, but as far as I know, there should not be a difference. Seems like a bug?

Comment: An interesting question is if we actually want users to link random IPv6 addresses. I'd personally never want to click on one, they're generally easier to obtain and more anonymous than IPv4 addresses or subdomains and I can't really think of a legitimate usecase. However, the point that the current behaviour is inconsistent remains.

Comment: Keep in mind that SE has [historically not taken a liking to IP address links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131639/are-ip-address-links-valid-in-posts).

Comment: `<http://[::1]>` also doesn’t work.